# "Edit with elementor" button missing

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I've got a site hosted on altervista.org that works with WordPress 5.9.3.
I use Elementor for my pages. I've recently installed a plugin called "Redirection", and since then the button "edit with Elementor" disappeared. I've deleted Redirection and reinstalled Elementor but it still doesn't work. I tried to switch my current theme (blocksky) with a default one but the problem persists. I've deactivated all the other plugins except for Elementor and the button is still missing. I've cleared all the caches that I could. Pages' checkbox in elementor's settings is checked. All the plugins are up to date (I've also tried downgrading elementor but nothing). All the elementor's experiments are deactivated. What can I do?

Here are elementor logs:

```
JS: 2022-03-26 15:40:48 [error X 1261][https://sharingnotes.altervista.org/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/pickr/pickr.min.js?ver=1.5.0:2:16820] Cannot read property \'clone\' of null 
JS: 2022-03-26 15:40:50 [error X 34][https://sharingnotes.altervista.org/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/pickr/pickr.min.js?ver=1.5.0:2:21012] Cannot read property \'changestop\' of null 
JS: 2022-03-30 15:18:51 [error X 22][https://sharingnotes.altervista.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:31703] this[binder] is not a function 
JS: 2022-04-02 08:39:04 [error X 2][https://sharingnotes.altervista.org/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/editor.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:515679] Cannot read property \'getBoundingClientRect\' of null 
Log: showing 5 of 5
2022-05-01 15:23:03 [info] Elementor data updater process has been queued. [array (
  'plugin' => 'Elementor',
  'from' => '3.6.1',
  'to' => '3.6.5',
)]
2022-05-01 15:23:14 [info] elementor::elementor_updater Started 
2022-05-01 15:23:14 [info] Elementor/Upgrades - _on_each_version Start  
2022-05-01 15:23:14 [info] Elementor/Upgrades - _on_each_version Finished 
2022-05-01 15:23:14 [info] Elementor data updater process has been completed. [array (
  'plugin' => 'Elementor',
  'from' => '3.6.1',
  'to' => '3.6.5',
)]
PHP: showing 1 of 1
PHP: 2022-05-01 16:01:33 [notice X 7][/membri/sharingnotes/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/experiments/experiments-reporter.php::89] Undefined index: title [array (
  'trace' => '
#0: Elementor\Core\Logger\Manager -> shutdown()
',
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating all third party plugin except Elementor should resolve the issue. Then make sure the relevant post type is checked from **Elementor > Settings**. Also have you followed this [documentation](https://elementor.com/help/the-edit-with-elementor-link-has-disappeared/) from Elementor? Let me know your findings.

Answer (score 0):

*general troubleshooting tips:*

**1. There may be a plugin which is causing this issue**. Try to deactivate all of your plugins (besides Elementor) and see if the Edit with Elementor link returns. If this solves the issue, reactivate each plugin, one by one, until the problem returns. This will help you discover which plugin is causing the problem.

**2. Your theme may also be causing this issue.** To test, temporarily switch your theme to Hello. (Your current theme settings will not be lost, and your site will return to normal as soon as you switch back to your normal theme). If the problem disappears with the use of the Hello theme, but reappears with the use of your theme, contact your theme’s developers for help to resolve the issue.

**3. Have you added any custom code?** Temporarily remove the code to see if the problem is solved. If so, you’ll need to troubleshoot your custom code to resolve the issue.